# Assign values to a df$column with values calculated in another df in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

*Codes for the dfs are at the end.*

I have two dataframes. **The first df is meteo data from 3 different stations :**

```
  site     date        temp
   X    2021-01-01      14
   X    2021-01-02      NA
   X    2021-01-03      10
   X    2021-01-04      14
   X    2021-01-05      10
   X    2021-01-06      10
   X    2021-01-07      13
   X    2021-01-08      12
   X    2021-01-09      13
   X    2021-01-10       7
   X    2021-01-11       9
   X    2021-01-12       6
   X    2021-01-13       8
   Y    2021-01-01      10
   Y    2021-01-02      14
   Y    2021-01-03       5
   Y    2021-01-04       7
   Y    2021-01-05       7
   Y    2021-01-06       9
   Y    2021-01-07       6
   Y    2021-01-08      12
   Y    2021-01-09      10
   Y    2021-01-10       9
   Y    2021-01-11      13
   Y    2021-01-12      13
   Y    2021-01-13      NA
   Y    2021-01-14       8
   Y    2021-01-15      11
   Y    2021-01-16       5
   Y    2021-01-17      11
   Y    2021-01-18      13
   Y    2021-01-19      11
   Y    2021-01-20       9
   Y    2021-01-21       9
   Y    2021-01-22       5
   Y    2021-01-23       6
   Y    2021-01-24      14
   Y    2021-01-25      10
   Y    2021-01-26       7
   Z    2021-01-01       9
   Z    2021-01-02      NA
   Z    2021-01-03      12
   Z    2021-01-04       6
   Z    2021-01-05       5
   Z    2021-01-06       7
   Z    2021-01-07       7
   Z    2021-01-08       5
   Z    2021-01-09       7
   Z    2021-01-10       7
   Z    2021-01-11      15
   Z    2021-01-12       8
   Z    2021-01-13       5
   Z    2021-01-14       6
   Z    2021-01-15       5
   Z    2021-01-16      12
   Z    2021-01-17       8
   Z    2021-01-18       7
   Z    2021-01-19       6
   Z    2021-01-20      13
   Z    2021-01-21      14
   Z    2021-01-22       8
   Z    2021-01-23      11
   Z    2021-01-24       7
```

**The second df consists of observations made on the same site than the meteo stations.**
There is a trap at each station. Every couple days, the trap is emptied and the different species that were trapped are counted separately. For each site in `df2`, the date of `pose` is always the day after the date of `withdrawal` of the precedent entree (row). In this exemple, the species are in the `obs` column. They are named `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `F` and `G`. `freq` is the number of individuals that were trapped for that specie.

```
  site    pose        withdrawal    obs    freq
   X    2021-01-01    2021-01-03      A      31
   X    2021-01-01    2021-01-03      B      42
   X    2021-01-04    2021-01-05      A      14
   X    2021-01-06    2021-01-13      D      16
   X    2021-01-06    2021-01-13      F      36
   Y    2021-01-01    2021-01-04      G      49
   Y    2021-01-01    2021-01-04      A      29
   Y    2021-01-01    2021-01-04      C      45
   Y    2021-01-05    2021-01-14      D      25
   Y    2021-01-05    2021-01-14      A      50
   Y    2021-01-15    2021-01-14      B      40
   Y    2021-01-19    2021-01-26      B      39
   Z    2021-01-01    2021-01-03      C      25
   Z    2021-01-04    2021-01-05      F       3
   Z    2021-01-04    2021-01-05      B      16
   Z    2021-01-06    2021-01-14      C      19
   Z    2021-01-15    2021-01-19      A      12
   Z    2021-01-15    2021-01-19      B      26
   Z    2021-01-15    2021-01-19      F       2
   Z    2021-01-20    2021-01-24      A      24
```

**I want to add a `mean_T` column to `df2` where I would store the mean temperature for each entree in `df2`.**

For `ID = 1`, the mean temperature would be calculated with the entrees `2021-01-01`, `2021-01-02` and `2021-01-03` in `df1`, where `site = 'X'`.

With simpler dfs, I used this code the get the mean temperature. It works if I only have one entree per date, per site in `df2`, which is not the case.

```
df1 <- split(df1, with(df1, site), subset(df1, select = -site) )
df1 <- lapply(df1, function(x) x[(names(x) %in% c("ID", "date", "temp"))])

df2 <- split(df2, with(df2, site), subset(df2, select = -site) )
df2 <- lapply(df2, function(x) x[(names(x) %in% c("ID", "pose", "withdrawal"))])

 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
```

Then, this code gave me the mean temperature. Credits go to **@TarJae** :

```
 mean_X <- df2$X %>% 
      pivot_longer(-ID, values_to = "date") %>% 
       full_join(df1$X, by= "date") %>% 
      arrange(date) %>% 
      fill(ID, .direction = "down") %>% 
       group_by(ID) %>% 
      summarise(mean_T = mean(temp, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
      left_join(df2$X, by="ID")
```

This chunk of code also worked credits go to **@Jon Spring** :

```
df2 %>%
    mutate(days = (withdrawal - pose + 1) %>% as.integer) %>%
    tidyr::uncount(days, .id = "row") %>%
    transmute(ID, date = pose + row - 1) %>%
    left_join(df1) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize(mean_T = mean(temp)) %>% 
    right_join(df2)
```

---

###### Here is the code to generate the dfs :

```
df1 <- data.frame( site = c(rep('X', 13), rep('Y', 26), rep('Z', 24) ) ,
                     date = c( seq( as.Date("2021-01-01"), by="day", length.out=13 ),
                               seq( as.Date("2021-01-01"), by="day", length.out=26 ),
                               seq( as.Date("2021-01-01"), by="day", length.out=24 )) , 
                     temp = c(14, NA,   10, 14, 10, 10, 13, 12, 13, 7,  9,  6,  8,  10, 14, 5,  7,  7,  9,  6,  12,
                              10,   9,  13, 13, NA, 8,  11, 5,  11, 13, 11, 9,  9,  5,  6,  14, 10, 7,  9,  NA, 12, 
                               6,   5,  7,  7,  5,  7,  7,  15, 8,  5,  6, 5,   12, 8,  7,  6,  13, 14, 8,  11, 7) ) 

df2 <- data.frame( site = c( rep('X', 5), rep('Y', 7), rep('Z', 8) ) , 
                   pose = as.Date( c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-06", 
                                     "2021-01-06", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", 
                                     "2021-01-05", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-15", "2021-01-19" ,
                                     "2021-01-01", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-06",
                                     "2021-01-15", "2021-01-15", "2021-01-15", "2021-01-20") ) ,
                   withdrawal = as.Date( c( "2021-01-03", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-13", 
                                            "2021-01-13", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-04", 
                                            "2021-01-14", "2021-01-14", "2021-01-14", "2021-01-26" ,
                                            "2021-01-03", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-14",
                                            "2021-01-19", "2021-01-19", "2021-01-19", "2021-01-24" ) ) , 
                   obs = c( 'A', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'B' , 
                            'C', 'F', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'F', 'A') ,
                   freq = c(31, 42, 14, 16, 36, 49, 29, 45, 25, 50, 40, 39, 25, 3, 16, 19, 12, 26, 2, 24) ) 
df2 <- cbind(ID = 1:nrow(df2), df2)
```

###### English is not my first language. If something doesn't make sense, fell free to let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I expand `df2` to make a dataset with one row per day

```
df3 <- do.call(rbind,by(df2, 
   list(df2$ID), 
   function(d) data.frame(d,dates=d$pose:d$withdrawal)))
```

Now I merge `df1` into this new dataset.  I first need to convert the date to a numeric to match `df3`

```
df1$dates <- as.numeric(df1$date)
df4 <- merge(df1, df3,by=c("site", "dates"))
```

Now I can aggregate the new dataset by taking the mean temp over each day

```
aggregate(data=df4, temp ~ freq + site + obs + pose + withdrawal +ID, mean)      


   freq site obs       pose withdrawal ID      temp
1    31    X   A 2021-01-01 2021-01-03  1 12.000000
2    42    X   B 2021-01-01 2021-01-03  2 12.000000
3    14    X   A 2021-01-04 2021-01-05  3 12.000000
4    16    X   D 2021-01-06 2021-01-13  4  9.750000
5    36    X   F 2021-01-06 2021-01-13  5  9.750000
6    49    Y   G 2021-01-01 2021-01-04  6  9.000000
7    29    Y   A 2021-01-01 2021-01-04  7  9.000000
8    45    Y   C 2021-01-01 2021-01-04  8  9.000000
9    25    Y   D 2021-01-05 2021-01-14  9  9.666667
10   50    Y   A 2021-01-05 2021-01-14 10  9.666667
11   40    Y   B 2021-01-15 2021-01-14 11  9.500000
12   39    Y   B 2021-01-19 2021-01-26 12  8.875000
13   25    Z   C 2021-01-01 2021-01-03 13 10.500000
14    3    Z   F 2021-01-04 2021-01-05 14  5.500000
15   16    Z   B 2021-01-04 2021-01-05 15  5.500000
16   19    Z   C 2021-01-06 2021-01-14 16  7.444444
17   12    Z   A 2021-01-15 2021-01-19 17  7.600000
18   26    Z   B 2021-01-15 2021-01-19 18  7.600000
19    2    Z   F 2021-01-15 2021-01-19 19  7.600000
20   24    Z   A 2021-01-20 2021-01-24 20 10.600000
```